# hiding a column th in html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to hide the ID th in my view, im using jquery datatable, is there anyway to hide it?  I don't want to see it in my front end my html and JS as below.

HTML :

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>ID</th> 
     <th>Upload Date</th>
     <th>File Name</th>
     <th>Bank</th>
     <th>Upload By</th>
     <th>filepath</th>
     <th>summarypath</th>
     <th>ACTION</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

JS :

```js
"aoColumns": [
    { "sName": "FileStatus", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "100px" },
    { "sName": "ID", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "200px" },
    { "sName": "Crdt", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "100px", "sType": "date" },
    { "sName": "FileName", "sClass": "left" },
    { "sName": "BankName", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "100px" },
    { "sName": "Crid", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "150px" },
    { "sName": "filepath", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "10px", "bVisible": false },
    { "sName": "summarypath", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "10px", "bVisible": false },
    { "sName": "", "sWidth": "100px", "bSearchable": false,  "bSortable": false, "fnRender": function (oObj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns), you could try :

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "sName": "FileStatus", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "100px" },
    { "sName": "ID", "bVisible": false },
    { "sName": "Crdt", "sClass": "left", "sWidth": "100px", "sType": "date" },
    // Following the code
```

Comment: zl3n you are great dude, thanks but explain to m why atarget 0?what does it do?and ya confirm you are voted

Comment: `"aTargets": [0]` should be removed, but setting `"bVisible": false` is a correct answer.